# Calculating business days using BusinessHours class

Tags: apex, datetime, businesshours

Our business has a requirement to calculate a due date on a case by using the created date and adding business hours, or business days. When we calculate business days it converts the days to 24 hours and divides the result by the business hours(10 hours) which is giving us wrong due dates.

Example:

If our created date is today(8/5/16) and we add 5 business days it converts it to 120 hours. It then divides the hours by the business hours which is 12 business days and adds that to the created date which is incorrect.

Is there anyway to make the days convert to amount of time in a business day(which could be dynamic based on BusinessHours) instead of 5 business days being 5 24 hours days?

Heres the code we have currently:

```
Long interval = c.CreatedDate.addDays(Integer.valueOf(amountOfTimeString)).getTime() - c.CreatedDate.getTime();
c.SLA_Due_Date__c = BusinessHours.add(bh.Id, c.CreatedDate, interval);
```

I would wish to avoid dividing the interval by a magic number and have it instead be dynamic by the BusinessHours.

Any help would be great

BusinessHours API:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_businesshours.htm

Edit: adding complete method of snippet

```
private static Boolean setDate(Object amountOfTime, Object timeType, Case c, BusinessHours bh, SObject referenceObject) {
    Decimal amountOfTimeString = (Decimal) amountOfTime;
    String timeTypeString = (String) timeType;
    if(!String.isEmpty(String.valueOf(amountOfTimeString))) {
        if(timeTypeString == 'Business Hours') {
            Long interval = c.CreatedDate.addHours(Integer.valueOf(amountOfTimeString)).getTime() - c.CreatedDate.getTime(); 
            c.SLA_Due_Date__c = BusinessHours.add(bh.Id, c.CreatedDate, interval);
        } else if(timeTypeString == 'Calendar Hours') {
            c.SLA_Due_Date__c = c.CreatedDate.addHours(Integer.valueOf(amountOfTimeString));
        } else if(timeTypeString == 'Business Days') {
            System.debug('Amount of time string: ' + amountOfTimeString);
            Long interval = c.CreatedDate.addDays(Integer.valueOf(amountOfTimeString)).getTime() - c.CreatedDate.getTime();
            System.debug('Created Date: ' + c.CreatedDate);
            c.SLA_Due_Date__c = BusinessHours.add(bh.Id, c.CreatedDate, interval);
        } else if(timeTypeString == 'Calendar Days') {
             c.SLA_Due_Date__c = c.CreatedDate.addDays(Integer.valueOf(amountOfTimeString));
        }

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing the point of `BusinessHours.add`. Just use `Integer.valueOf(amountOfTimeString)` instead of what you have.

Comment: Well amountOfTime is just a digit. It could be 5 days or 5 hours. If I were to put 5 into that method, it would only add 5 milliseconds.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I updated the post to include the whole method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be more clear to calculate the diff you want algebraically. If you want 10 hours per day, and you have an `Integer` that represents how many days you want to add, then you need to add:

```
Long days = 30;
Long interval = days * 10 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
//                 d    h    m    s     ms
```

What you have done is add 24 hours per day. It would be equivalent to

```
Long days = 30;
Long interval = days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
//                 d    h    m    s     ms
```

If you want it to be more dynamic, you can try an iterative approach. Something like:

```
public static Datetime addBusinessDays(Datetime pointer, Integer days)
{
    Integer elapsed = 0;
    while (elapsed < days)
    {
        pointer = pointer.addDays(1);
        if (BusinessHours.isWithin(bh.Id, pointer)) elapsed++;
        else pointer = BusinessHours.nextStartDate(bh.Id);
    }
    return pointer;
}
```

Comment: I would like to avoid the magic hardcoded numbers. 10 is your usual business day, however, there could be half days or holidays and thats all set up in BusinessHours. I would like this to be as dynamic as possible

Comment: I like the iterative approach. Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: correction:  `else pointer = BusinessHours.nextStartDate(bh.Id, pointer);`